# AFNetworking 1.3.1 often goes to failure Block in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, ios8, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to upload some content to server using `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. It is working good in iOS 7 but in case of iOS 8 mostly this call goes to failure.
I'm getting this error:

```
Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.), NSErrorFailingURLKey.
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What about formatting your question? ;-)

Comment: what formatting you need sandro?

Comment: Check your question. I did it for you. I think your question now looks more appealing. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLErrorDomain error -999` is `NSURLErrorCancelled`

[You can review the error codes here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)

You might get this error due to a request timing out, or resubmitting the same request more than once. Without further code there isn't much to expand on, but have you ensured that you haven't lost your wifi settings since upgrading to iOS 8?

BTW you can use `NSErrorFailingURLKey` to find the failing URL - try putting it straight into Safari and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is being discussed here :
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314
it seems to be related to keepalive implementation in iOS8, no solution available on client side for now, if you can configure the http server, disabling http keepalive should solve your issue ...